# Review opportunities

Tags: support

I wonder whether an individual has the chance to review his own post, which has come up for review due to others. I'm sure I've posted and it's been taken down, but I haven't been given this opportunity. If one gets this chance, one could change the post.

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure if the user gets a post notice or anything either.

Comment: May be more appropriate on Meta Stack Exchange as it is a question about the system in general and not just our site.